# Misaligned navbar buttons on smaller view

Tags: navbar

I'm new to html and bootstrap-4 in general so please be lenient. I'm doing a website for one school project and I have a problem with the navbar I created. It works completely fine until you view the page in a smaller view than 575 px. The buttons suddenly misalign and they are stacked on top of each other vertically rather than horizontally. I want them to stay in the same horizontal position. It's just a school project, so it doesn't have to be perfect, but I really want to make this one thing to work.

I would be grateful for your help!

```
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
 <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">MENU</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ml-4">
      <a class="nav-link" href="HOMEPAGE.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="PAGE.html">History</a>
    </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Missions</a>
    </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
    </li>
       </ul>
</nav>
```